# Collecting different HTML Input Elements from different Html Page Location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

[image]

Suppose I have a page like this, the left part has a form which has two input element, I can't put the right part element inside my left form tag because of page positioning which is impossible.

How can I submit the value of the left part and the right part together after the user click submit while they are forced to be separated ?

any idea, any code or anything that can help me ...

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessibility reasons both input areas should belong to the same `form`. Not everyone will be using JavaScript, and for those users your collected data would be nonsensical.

What you can do is simply wrap both of your columns within a `form` rather than just that one section within one column. Assuming your existing markup looks like this:

```html
<div>
    <form>
        <input />
        <textarea></textarea>
        <input />
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <input />
</div>
```

Simply change that to look like this:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <input />
        <textarea></textarea>
        <input />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to chain the inputs to that form without just wrapping the whole page inside the form element. that's kinda weired dude !

Comment: @Mehdi as I mentioned, for accessibility reasons you can't really do this with JavaScript. If you do you will end up collecting a load of invalid information from users who have JavaScript disabled. Doing this doesn't invalidate your HTML.

Comment: do you know about tabindex in input elements ? that can't help here ? I just heard about it a little bit

Comment: `tabindex` controls the order in which elements are accessed through your keyboard's tab key. This doesn't relate to submitting forms.